# In Objective-C Can you define a class in two different files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class

I know one file can define many different classes. What about the other way around? Can one class is defined in several different files?

Say you want to add method or property of classes you wrote (rather than the framework classes). Can you do that?

Notice I do not want to change original .m file and I want to add property which is something category cannot do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class can only have one @implementation block, so no you can not define a class in multiple files.

If there is some reason you can't add code to the original class @implementation, the alternatives are subclassing or categories.

Comment: Well, the implementation is automatically generated by core data code generator. I don't want to change it. But yea subclassing seems to be the way to go.

Comment: If you are talking about an NSManagedObject subclass that Xcode generated the header and .m for, then there is no reason not to add code directly to those files...just don't break the code that is already there.

Comment: What about if the core data changes and I have to regenerate the code?

Comment: The appropriate way to handle that is with subclassing. There is a tool that can help with that: http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

Alternatively:

1. nicely - create category in other file
2. not nicely - #include other file in main implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with categories.

```
//File1.h
@interface Object : NSObject

-(void)method;
@end

//File1.m
@implementation Object
-(void)method
{
    NSLog (@"hello");
}

@end

//File2.h
@interfacae Object(ObjectExtention) //How you declare a category
-(void)methodTwo;
@end

//File2.m
@implementation Object(ObjectExtention)
-(void)methodTwo
{
   NSLog (@"Categorie Method");
}

@end

//File3.m

#import "File1.h"
#import "File2.h"
int main()
{
    Object obj = [[Object alloc] init];
    [obj method]; //Declared in first file
    [obj methodTwo]; //Declared in second file where we had our categorie defined
    return 0;
}
```

You can do this with methods, however, you can't add more instance variables to a object like a categorie.

Comment: Categories cannot add objects

Comment: Categories extends an object, not add objects.